# REST server and video streaming

Tags: java, rest, video, jersey, streaming

I am building a restful web server with jersey in conjunction with an android app. One of the thing that the server needs to do is to save a video uploaded from an android client and be able to see that video in streaming on other android devices using my app.

I wrote this little test function:

```
@GET
@Path("video")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response video() {
   File file = new File("C:/Data/video.mp4");

   return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
       .build();
 }
```

and seems to randomly work. sometimes the client just loads for ages and i need to close the app. when i close i get this exceptions:

```
An I/O error has occurred while writing a response message entity to the container output stream.
```

that error makes me think that when the connection is pretty slow like with 3g instead of wiki, the load takes a lot of time and when i close the app the connection closes so the server can't write on it. so here is my doubt:

1) streams should be used with UDP but udp doesn't have handshaking so that type of error makes no sense to me. does it means i am using tcp?

2) im i actually sending a multipart file? because it seems like it just download the entire file and then start the play.

my final thought is: is it worth to do this with rest? there is any external service that can store and stream the file for me, maybe adding some service like compression and stuff like that? and if not how should i do this? can u guyz show me an example?

ty for the patience and sorry for my english :D

Comment: You should use a streaming server for that. Like Wowza, VideoLan ...